# Using KProperty with List of objects

Tags: kotlin, reflection, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We're using Spring Data MongoDB with Kotlin. Kotlin comes with some nice typesafe Criteria Extensions (`org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.TypedCriteriaExtensions`).

given:

```kotlin
data class Foo(
  val id: String, 
  val oneBar: Bar, 
  val bars: List<Bar>)

data class Bar(val thingy: String)
```

You can use it to build Criteria in a typesafe manner, such as:

```kotlin
criterion = criterion + (Foo::id isEqualTo "id")
```

If you have a nested object `Bar`, you can use

```kotlin
criterion = criterion + (Foo::oneBar / Bar::thingy isEqualTo "thingy")
```

How do you use `KProperty` when you have an object `Foo` with a list of `Bar`s and you want to write a Criteria based on a field of Bar

What I want to do is to filter on a property of Bar.

This doesn't work, but I want to do something like this:

```kotlin
criterion = criterion + (Foo::bars / <thing with list> / Bar::thingy isEqualTo "thingy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to use elemMatch for type-safe queries which should do the trick:

```kotlin
Foo::bars elemMatch (Bar::thingy isEqualTo "thingy")
```